# Force an "update" on all records in a table, without actually changing anything

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

TLDR; How can I force an "update" on all records in a table, without actually changing anything?

A little background:
In our application we have a number of large tables with many rows and many columns. Among those columns, there are a number of `nvarchar(max)` columns containing JSON. So the total table size is quite large (multiple gigabytes)

For certain list-overview screens in our application, we fetch all records from that table, but without the JSON columns. Still, that fetch is very I/O-heavy on the SQL server due to the massive amount of table reads, even if the JSON itself was not returned in the query.

To fix this, one of the architects came up with the idea of duplicating the table into a "list"-version of the table, e.g. the same table-structure as the original table, but without the JSON columns. It solved the problem of the heavy I/O when fetching the "list", but of course introduced the headaches of keeping both the "real" tables and the lighter "list" tables in sync...

Now, after doing a little research, I've found that `nvarchar(max)` columns are by default using "in row" storage instead of the "out of row".
(ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms173530(v=sql.105)

So I assume that changing that table option to "out of row" would have a large impact on the I/O when fetching records that don't need the JSON-columns.

But setting `EXEC sp_tableoption 'schema.table', 'large value types out of row', 1` is just setting that option, and changes nothing to the data.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189087(v=sql.105):

> When the large value types out of row option value is changed, existing varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), and xml values are not immediately converted. The storage of the strings is changed as they are subsequently updated. Any new values inserted into a table are stored according to the table option in effect.

So, now my question is, how can I force this "update" to all records in the table, without actually changing anything, but so that all JSON-columns have will store their content out-of-row?
And after that, do I need to "compress" the table or anything to optimize the performance? (Kind of like rebuilding an index)

Comment: You can update without change as `update mytable set mycolumn = mycolumn` need to test whether that works.

Comment: if you still have the same problem without fetching the json columns, than maybe their not the problem. How exact are you quering the rows without the json column ?

Comment: "And after that, do I need to "compress" the table or anything to optimize the performance?" - up to you - does it help you solve your problem?

Comment: How about simply moving those columns in another table with one-one relationship? Then you can do `select * from t join j on t.id = j.id`. Or even create a view.

Comment: You could avoid all of that by creating a covering index of just the columns you want, same effect as a separate table, none of the maintenance.

Comment: Instead of creating the second table it was enough to create nonclustered index with all the non blob columns included, this way you effectively has the second copy of the table excluding blob columns and you have no problem of "sysncronization

Comment: You could also just split your table into two. One `TableA` with all the columns but the JSON column. And one `TableB` with a foreign key to `TableA` and the JSON column. So when you want to read without JSON, you select from `TableA` and if you want the json (or a read with json) you select from `TableB` or join `TableA` and `TableB` ...

Comment: I agree it sounds like some normalisation is needed to your table schema here. Large infrequently used columns should reside in a dedicated table, imho. Interesting to learn about the tableoptions though.

Answer (score 1):

> So, now my question is, how can I force this "update" to all records in the table, without actually changing anything, but so that all JSON-columns have will store their content out-of-row?

`update my_table set my_json_column = my_json_column`

will rewrite all the blob columns, pushing them off-row.

> And after that, do I need to "compress" the table or anything to optimize the performance? (Kind of like rebuilding an index)

Yes.  The rows-per-page will still be terrible after you move the column off-row.

`alter table my_table rebuild`

should fix that.

You can check all this with

```
select index_id, alloc_unit_type_desc, page_count
from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),object_id('dbo.my_table'),-1,0,'detailed')
```

Answer (score 1):

**You are barking up the wrong tree.** It's more efficient to keep the data in-page.

You just need to maintain a separate index that doesn't contain that column.

```sql
CREATE INDEX IX ON YourTable
  (YourPrimaryKey)
  INCLUDE (AllOtherColumnsHereApartFromJson);
```

Comment: As I said in a comment :)